# Adobe Air mobile bypass http proxy Kindle Fire HD

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, proxy, kindle

My issue is that my flash app is not using the Kindle Fire HD proxy settings. When holding down on the currently used wifi connection brings up advanced options were I was able to setup a proxy.

I installed Charles proxy along with the ssl certificate and used it as my proxy. I know it's working since I can see the web traffic when I use the device's web browser. When I turn off Charles proxy I can no longer view webpages. When I try and see my app's UrlLoader http GET/POST calls, nothing shows up in Charles. Calls are still going through even when Charles is closed. Is it possible to get it to work?

Charles proxy: http://www.charlesproxy.com/
Android/Charles setup instructions: http://jaanus.com/post/17476995356/debugging-http-on-an-android-phone-or-tablet-with
Flex SDK: 4.6.0
Air: 3.1